# Apply Xslt to Xml and save output c#

Tags: c#, xml, xslt, windows-forms-designer

I have made a windows forms program that takes a CSV file views it and then makes an XML file saved separately I have now made two XSLT files I wish to apply to the XML on a button press ( two buttons ) I have been trying to use this to just apply it with no luck so far any help would be appreciated.

```
private void btnXmlToXml_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        XPathDocument myXPathDoc = new XPathDocument(@"C:\StockFile\CsvXmlout.xml");
        XslCompiledTransform myXslTrans = new XslCompiledTransform();
        myXslTrans.Load(@"C:\StockFile\XmlToXml.xslt");
        XmlTextWriter myWriter = new XmlTextWriter(@"C:\StockFile\CsvXmlToXmlOut.xml", null);
        myXslTrans.Transform(myXPathDoc, null, myWriter);
    }
```

but receive an error "'System.IO.IOException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
"

I am open to a different method of getting it to work if you have one please try to explain how it works as I am learning.

Comment: I have now realised that the error where coming from multiple button presses and I have to implement some code to stop it running multiple times.

Comment: Note that there is an overload of the `Transform` method that takes two strings with file names/paths to simply transform an input file to an output file so there is no need to create an XPathDocument and an XmlTextWriter for your purpose, you can simply use `myXslTrans.Transform(@"C:\StockFile\CsvXmlout.xml", @"C:\StockFile\CsvXmlToXmlOut.xml");`. That saves two lines of code and is more flexible as the XSLT processor can do any input treatment like white space stripping and in particular any output serialization defined in the XSLT. If you use XmlTextWriter any `xsl:output` is ignored.